# django step through the code

Tags: django, debugging

is it possible to to a step through the code in django ( i mean step through while debugging)

Comment: not by using breakpoint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address debugging, instead of step-based debugging in the framework itself it is more preferable in the Django community to provide unit tests.  If you are building a module, [Django provides facilities to test applications](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/).  For step-through debugging you may need an IDE to handle it: AFAIK Django doesn't provide a facility to do that.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do that by using the Python Debugger module, `pdb`.  I have covered the topic of [debugging Django applications](http://ayaz.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/debugging-django-applications/) on my blog before.  In an nutshell, if you are using the Django development server, you can easily step through your Django application by placing a breakpoint with the statements `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at any point in your view code where you want to start debugging, and then step through the debugger that is invoked on the shell where the Django development server was running from.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as you're running in the development server.

If so, just put this into your code at the point you want to stop:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and you will be dumped into the debugger on the console, from where you can step through to your heart's content.

Comment: Alternative is ipdb. To install "easy_install ipdb".

To use in your code, "import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()"